# Sensenet : Node permission getting older value after updated permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sensenet

I have change node permission by updating 'SecurityEntries' and 'SecurityCustomeEntries' tables using direct database call (not through API). I have found that it is fetching older value from API, even database table's values has been updated successfully. I need latest updated value from API. How can I get it?

Update Query For Deny AddNew permission

```
Update SecurityEntries set PermissionValue7 = '2' AND PermissionValue15 = '2' where DefinedOnNodeId = 'XXXX' AND PrincipalId='XXXXX';
```

Check 'AddNew' Permission after update above query (which is returning true)

```
node.Security.HasPermission((IUser)emailUserObj, PermissionType.AddNew);
```

The above HasPermission method of API is returning older value.

I observed one more thing that once I have create any other new node then it the it is ('HasPermission' method) showing latest value of permissions for above node.

Is there any caching or something else?

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sensenet caches permission values to speed up permission evaluation. It would be very slow if we looked into the db every time a permission check is needed. This is one of the reasons why it is not advisable to modify permissions directly in the database. Another reason is it may break something if you make an incompatible change :).

Please do it through our API, either using the server-side c# permission API (referencing the main Services package) or the client side c# api (using the [.Net client](https://github.com/SenseNet/sn-client-dotnet)).

Changing permissions, creating content or restarting the site resets this cache, this is why you see changes after you create something.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I am not using API because it is taking too much time to execute so I am changing permissions by direct database call. Is there any way to clear that permission cache ?

Comment: Modifying permissions in the db is bad practice. Security info is preloaded in memory on all app instances (web nodes) which makes permission evaluation very fast. Modifications happen in the in-memory structure first than written to the db. After that all other app instances have to be notified about the change. This is why the suggested solution is to use the _SnAclEditor_ fluent API for this task. It can handle lots of modifications in one step. You may do any number of changes, they will be performed in one go when you call the _Apply_ method.